# How to write JavaScript in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse for java coding. Can I use JavaScript in eclipse? If yes, How to use it? Please give ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to edit Javascript within Eclipse, just install the WTP (Web Tools Project), there is one in there. Edit: You cannot execute Javascript from within Eclipse, but you can use, for example, Firefox with Venkman or Firebug to run the actual file in a browser.

Comment: "run the actual fine"? what's an actual fine?

Answer (score 6):

I use the excellent [Aptana studio](http://www.aptana.com/) [eclipse plugin](http://www.aptana.com/downloads/start).

Comment: +1 Aptana is quite nice. I've yet to find anything better for Eclipse.